# Dynamic Memory Allocation with Cython

Tags: python, cython

I have this code that just runs too slow.

```
 returnMask = []
 for curPage in range(numPages):
    print curPage
    curPageAddr = curPage + startPage
    cumMask = np.ones((numBytes)).astype(int) * 0xff 
    for maskFunction, maskAction in maskPattern:
            #maskArgs['funcArgs']['startPage'] = curPageAddr
            #maskArgs['funcArgs']['numPages'] = 1
            inputArgs['funcArgs']['startPage'] = curPageAddr
            inputArgs['funcArgs']['numPages'] = 1
            curMaskName, curMaskData = maskFunction(inputArgs)
            if (maskAction == 'include'):
                    maskIn = np.array(curMaskData).astype(int)
            if (maskAction == 'exclude'):
                    maskIn = (~np.array(curMaskData).astype(int)) & 0xff
            cumMask = cumMask & maskIn
    print "cumMask size %d" % len(cumMask)
    returnMask += cumMask.astype(int).tolist()
```

Basically, my outer for loop is looping 2000 times and each time appending a list of 2048 bytes into returnMask. I was thinking that I could use Cython, change returnMask into a dynamically allocated c array and that might help speed up my code. Can anyone tell me if this is a good way of tackling this problem?

Comment: Please post the whole code. Switch to `xrange` instead of `range`. Also, your code is probably spending a large amount of time writing to the terminal due to the print statements.

Comment: To post code, make a trip to [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say - how slow is it (in seconds)?

My first guess is that your `maskFunction` is taking all the time.

Second, `np.array().astype()` is chaining together two functions that are both slow, and running `~` is a third function. Then your outer loop has `astype` and `tolist`, which are both slow. Doing those things in Cython is where you'll really see improvement.

I really doubt `range` and `print` are taking significant time.

Have you measured the bottlenecks? I usually put in some `time.time()` calls around various functions and average across the whole loop:

```
dt = np.zeros( (len(loop),) )
for i in loop:
    t = time.time()
    slow_function()
    dt[i] = time.time() - t
print "avg. time for slow_function was %.3f s" % dt.mean()
```